# Is it possible to design headless tests with JMeter/Selenium? (and Docker)

Tags: docker, selenium

There are of course Dockerizations of Selenium and JMeter - but can they work together? All the tutorials I can find discuss desktop solutions so not headless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMeter supports headless operation, in fact it's even the recommended mode for best load testing results. From [Non-GUI Mode (Command Line mode)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui):

> For load testing, you must run JMeter in this mode (Without the GUI)
>   to get the optimal results from it. To do so, use the following
>   command options:
>
> **-n**
>       This specifies JMeter is to run in non-gui mode

As for Selenium, things are a bit debatable, the [Does Selenium support headless browser testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568899/does-selenium-support-headless-browser-testing) SO post is probably interesting, personally I find [Ross Patterson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7573839/4495081)'s and [General Redneck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11714359/4495081)'s answers most useful - basically recommending the use of a virtual X server ([Xvfb](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml), for example) instead of a headless browser.

A nice related post: [How To Run Your Tests Headlessly with Xvfb](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless).